# Another way get class Type from within class in swift

Tags: swift

```
protocol Foo {    }

class MyClass: Foo {
    public let ref: Foo.Type = MyClass.self //another way to call MyClass.self?
}
```

I'm currently using MyClass.self to get the Type. Is there another way to do this? It's purely syntactic, I was just hoping to use something like self.Type.

Comment: MyClass.self is the best way to do it. What are you looking to do?

Comment: What's the problem you're having, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the best you'll get until proposal [SE-0068 "Expanding Swift Self to class members and value types"](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md) is implemented in Swift 4.

Comment: I might be mistaken , but I believe that the once that proposal is introduced, `Self` will be analogous to `type(of: self)`, and therefore won't be accessible in the initialiser expression of an instance property (and even if, for example, in the initialiser expression of a lazy property, would not be `MyClass.self` for subclasses – although that being said, OP could well want the dynamic type). But in any case, I guess we'll have to wait and see just how it's implemented.